# if statement with ageDifference is not calculating correctly for the closest age

Tags: javascript

Something is wrong when I try to find the person who has the closest Age to Sonya Sotomayor. Can anyone detect my error?

```js
var notablePeople = {
  "Elvis Presley": new Date(1935, 0, 8),
  "Sonya Sotomayor": new Date(1954, 5, 25),
  "Franklin D. Roosevelt": new Date(1882, 0, 30),
  "Ben Carson": new Date(1951, 8, 18),
  "Roger Staubach": new Date(1942, 1, 5),
  "Steve Jobs": new Date(1955, 1, 24),
  "Albert Einstein": new Date(1879, 2, 14),
  "Isaac Asimov": new Date(1919, 9, 4),
  "Jada Pinkett Smith": new Date(1971, 8, 18),
  "Grace Hopper": new Date(1906, 11, 9),
  "Jared Nicholas": new Date(1995, 5, 16)
};


// Find who is closest in age to Sonya Sotomayor
var sonyaAge = notablePeople["Sonya Sotomayor"].getTime();
var ageDifference = Infinity;
var personClosest = "";

for (person in notablePeople) {
  // See if this person's age difference is closer
  if (person != "Sonya Sotomayor" && Math.abs(notablePeople[person].getTime() - sonyaAge) < ageDifference) {
    ageDifference = Math.abs(notablePeople[person].getTime() - sonyaAge);
    ageDifference = ageDifference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365;

    personClosest = person;
  }
}

console.log("\nClosest age difference is " + person + " with " + ageDifference + " years difference.");
```

Output:

```
/*This is not correct
 Closest age difference is Jared Nicholas with 19.473858447488585 years difference.
*/
```

Comment: You need to wait until after the loop to divide down the difference value.

Comment: Ok, that fixed the ageDifference! What about the personClosest-- it's still registering as Jared Nicholas even when I move it out of the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var notablePeople = {
    "Elvis Presley": new Date(1935, 0, 8),
    "Sonya Sotomayor": new Date(1954, 5, 25),
    "Franklin D. Roosevelt": new Date(1882, 0, 30),
    "Ben Carson": new Date(1951, 8, 18),
    "Roger Staubach": new Date(1942, 1, 5),
    "Steve Jobs": new Date(1955, 1, 24),
    "Albert Einstein": new Date(1879, 2, 14),
    "Isaac Asimov": new Date(1919, 9, 4),
    "Jada Pinkett Smith": new Date(1971, 8, 18),
    "Grace Hopper": new Date(1906, 11, 9),
    "Jared Nicholas": new Date(1995, 5, 16)
};


// Find who is closest in age to Sonya Sotomayor
var sonyaAge = notablePeople["Sonya Sotomayor"].getTime();
var ageDifference = Infinity;
var personClosest = "";

for (person in notablePeople) {
    // See if this person's age difference is closer
    console.log(person,Math.abs(notablePeople[person].getTime() - sonyaAge) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365);
    if (person != "Sonya Sotomayor" && (Math.abs(notablePeople[person].getTime() - sonyaAge) < ageDifference)) {
        ageDifference = Math.abs(notablePeople[person].getTime() - sonyaAge);
        personClosest = person;
    }
}
ageDifference = ageDifference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365;

console.log("\nClosest age difference is " + personClosest + " with " + ageDifference + " years difference.");
```

//You were comparing age in the wrong format and you were using person instead of personClosest

Comment: oh my goodness. I'm dumb. Yes, personClosest in the log thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to solve this problem. Its purpose is to take an array and reduce it to a single value. In this case, I've elected to reduce it to an object containing the name and age difference.

```js
var notablePeople = {
  "Elvis Presley": new Date(1935, 0, 8),
  "Sonya Sotomayor": new Date(1954, 5, 25),
  "Franklin D. Roosevelt": new Date(1882, 0, 30),
  "Ben Carson": new Date(1951, 8, 18),
  "Roger Staubach": new Date(1942, 1, 5),
  "Steve Jobs": new Date(1955, 1, 24),
  "Albert Einstein": new Date(1879, 2, 14),
  "Isaac Asimov": new Date(1919, 9, 4),
  "Jada Pinkett Smith": new Date(1971, 8, 18),
  "Grace Hopper": new Date(1906, 11, 9),
  "Jared Nicholas": new Date(1995, 5, 16)
};


// Find who is closest in age to Sonya Sotomayor
var sonya = "Sonya Sotomayor";
var sonyaAge = notablePeople[sonya].valueOf();
var ageDifference = Infinity;
var personClosest = '';
// Object.keys returns an array of property names (the people)
var personAge = Object.keys(notablePeople)
  // filter out Sonya
  .filter(key => key !== sonya)
  // go through the rest
  .reduce((agg, cur) => {
    // agg is the "aggregate value"; the object containing the name and age difference
    // from the last loop.
    // cur is the name of the person whose information we're looking at now
    // calculate the difference between them. The difference is positive.
    const diff = Math.abs(notablePeople[cur].valueOf() - sonyaAge);
    // return an object with the difference (if it's less than any of the previous)
    // and the name of the current person (again, if the difference is less than any of the previous)
    return { 
      ageDifference: diff < agg.ageDifference ? diff : agg.ageDifference, 
      person: diff < agg.ageDifference ? cur : agg.person
    }
  }, 
  // The initial value before any people have been examined
  { 
      ageDifference, 
      person: '' 
  }
);

// get the age difference in years (approx)
personAge.ageDifference = personAge.ageDifference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365;

console.log(`Closest age difference is ${personAge.person} with ${personAge.ageDifference} years difference.`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by base casing it (simplifying it), removing the long division and using plain numbers to inspect the routine. The issue was revealed pretty quickly; how you were testing the new ageDiff wasn't valid.

Base casing is a VERY useful technique. This might not really "technically" be base casing, but the notion is the same; reduce the complexity as much as possible and you can often find what's going on much more easily.

Take a look at the below. It renders the correct result (Staubach). Substitute back in your logic (myself, I would leave out the long division until you already know who the person is, there's no reason to run that logic if you're not sure you have the right person), and you should be able to move forward.

```
const notablePeople = {
  "Elvis Presley": 50,
  "Sonya Sotomayor": 30,
  "Franklin D. Roosevelt": 10,
  "Roger Staubach": 20,
  "Ben Carson": 45,
};


console.log ( getPerson () );

function getPerson () {
    let ageDiff = Infinity;
    let finalPerson = null;
    const sonyaAge = notablePeople["Sonya Sotomayor"];
    for (person in notablePeople) {
        if (person !== "Sonya Sotomayor") {
            const testAgeDiff = Math.abs(notablePeople[person] - sonyaAge);
            if ( testAgeDiff < ageDiff ) {
                ageDiff = testAgeDiff;
                finalPerson = person;
            }
        }
    }

    return finalPerson;
}
```

Another tip I'd present here; I intentionally made sure that the target I expected was not the last entry in the list. It's not unusual to see a dev write some logic like this, they run their test and get the expected result, so they think it's ok. If the target is the last entry in the inspected collection, you really don't know if you're getting the right answer, or if you're just returning the last item in the collection. I moved the numbers around and always got the result I expected.

Note this will not do things like check for same ages, invalid ages, etc, which your code should do. But I think with the procedure here, you'll see the logic bug and get the idea.

Last note; this could be done with a Array.filter as well, and you could make it more terse overall. Might be worth looking into that. Here, I wanted to stay as close to your original thinking as possible so you could see the logic bomb.